# Using SimpleCursorAdapter how can you query specific data from database

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, simplecursoradapter

I have a database from which I want to query and display only that data which has one type of similar field..
Say all rows have a day(Mon to sun) in them... I want to display all the rows that have Monday as the day...
I have used SimpleCursorAdapter to display all the rows from my database...
Basically, I want to know how i can query in SimpleCursorAdapter to display rows of the data having only say, Monday as the day...

Any help is appreciated...:)

The following code enables me to display all the data from my data base...

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.testlayout2);
     listContent = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);//.id..list);
    mDB = new DataSource(this);
    mDB.open();

    cursor = mDB.queueAll();
    String[] from = new String[]{
            MySQLiteHelper.KEY_START, MySQLiteHelper.KEY_END,
            MySQLiteHelper.KEY_SUBJECT, MySQLiteHelper.KEY_LOC,
            MySQLiteHelper.KEY_TEACHER };
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.tvStart, R.id.tvEnd,
            R.id.tvSub, R.id.tvLoc, R.id.tvTeacher };


            cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor,
            from, to);

        listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        listContent.setOnItemClickListener(listContentOnItemClickListener);
    }

}
```

I want the query to be like this..

```
  Cursor cursor = db.query(table, null, "day like " + "'%Monday%'",null, 
                                 null, null, null);
```

Got that... Sorry for the trouble. Please tell me where i am going wrong with this though..
I made this in the code to query the day and sort ascending by time..

```
 public Cursor queryDay(String days) {
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, mAllColumns, "day like " + 
                     days, null, null, null, Database.KEY_START + " ASC");
    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        return cursor;
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

However, I get this error,

```
   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Thursday: , 
   while compiling: SELECT _id, day,start_time, end_time, sub, location, 
   teacher FROM subjectTable WHERE day like Thursday ORDER BY start_time ASC
```

I am calling this like this..

```
 Cursor cursor = mDB.queryDay("Thursday");
 startManagingCursor(cursor);
```

Comment: And what specifically did not work? Also, is there a reason why you are using `query()` instead of `rawQuery()`?

Comment: No working of the code issues...
I want to know how i can query while using SimpleCursorAdapter...
the query i have provided is what i would like to put in my code with the cursorAdapter..
In short, Where and how should i put this line of code?

Comment: You need to quote your strings if you are going to use them manually via concatenation. Or use `?` and supply the day name in the subsequent `String[]` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves the second part of the question..

```
    public Cursor queryDay(String days) {
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, mAllColumns, "day like " 
     + "'" + days + "'", null,null, null, Database.KEY_START + " ASC");
    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        return cursor;
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't query the adapter, you query the database, it provides a cursor, which you pour into a list adapter.

```
mDbHelper.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE day_column = 'Monday');
```

Comment: I edited the question a little bit.. please resolve this question as well.. Thank you for your previous answer.

Comment: Found the solution to that as well..
Thank You fr your time...:)